# Detect eventDrop outside of calendar initialization in FullCalendar with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I am trying to listen for an event drop outside of the initialization of the calendar. In other words, I am trying to use the eventDrop function outside of the initialization code.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 editable: true,
 droppable: true,
 eventDrop: function(calEvent, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
  alert("Event Dropped!");
  eventlocations.push({
     location: calEvent.location,
     stopover: true
  });
 }
});
```

The reason for this that I want to run the function calculateAndDisplayRoute from Google Maps API every time an event is dropped.

```
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: destinationLatLng
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

 $('#calendar').on("drop",function(event, ui){//This does not work
      alert("Dropped!");
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
}
```

I tried to use the jQueryUI method on("drop") however, the event does not fire when I drop an event. Is it that the initialized fullCalendar element is not recognized as a jQueryUI droppable?

I'm at my wit's end here. Please help if you see a better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: "drop" is not a triggered JavaScript event which could be handled via "on", it's just an internal thing in fullcalendar which, when it gets to a certain point in the code, executes a specified callback function - which you specify in the options, as you have done. If you want something to happen when an event is dropped, you have to trigger it from that callback. So you can just move `calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);` into your callback. You might need to change it slightly to get the values of those variables correctly, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for that! I have fixed the issue by placing the entire fullcalendar initialization within the Google initMap() function to access the variables. This is the first time I am asking a question on stackoverflow, amazed to see how fast I can get a reply. Thanks for your comment and have a nice day ahead! :)